# How to get Instance of most basic Comparator for Class Integer

Tags: java

I have a constructor for a Heap-Class that takes a Comparator as an argument.

```
public Heap(Comparator<T> comparator) {
    this.comparator = comparator;
}
```

I simply want to store Integer Objects in the Heap; so how can I easily pass the most basic Comparator of class Integer.

I just want to use a.compareTo(b) to check if a is greater b without any modification, but this class needs me to explicitly pass a Comparator. Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--). Like,

```
Heap<Integer> heap = new Heap<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

(or use [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) if you want it in the reverse order).